# Form input strings to float

Tags: php, mysql, string, forms, floating-point

I have a php form thats capturing data, mostly strings, and submitting it to an XML file for storage.
I would like one of the inputs to to capture a price (float), and then subtract a percentage tied to that users account (stored in mysql), storing both values in the xml file.

the current code looks like this:

```
$price = $_POST['product_price'];
$our_price = $price - $user['product_fee'];
```

This obviously won't work because both values are being stored as strings, not floats.

There is an easy solution to this, I'm obviously missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) to parse the strings as floats.

```
$price = floatval($_POST['product_price']);
$our_price = $price - floatval($user['product_fee']);
```

**Warning:** Read the [WARNING](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) in the `php` float page about precision!!!

---

### **Update:**

To show two decimal points for the floating value, you could use the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function as:

```
echo number_format(floatval($our_price), 2, '.', '');
```

but keep in mind that this function again returns a `string`, which is expected as it is for presentation purposes mostly. If you wanted you could use `floatval` again on the returned string to parse it as a float:

```
$new_float = floatval(number_format(floatval($our_price), 2, '.', ''));
```

**Note:** For `number_format` here we also passed 3 optional parameters after the float:

1. Number `2` -> for the number of decimals needed
2. A dot (`.`) which is the decimal separator, and
3. A comma (`,`) which is the thousands separator to be used if needed.

Comment: Using floatval did the trick, but it sheds the 100th placeholder value, so for example 10 - .10 = 9.9, not 9.90. Any way to keep that?

Comment: Updated the answer for this using `echo number_format($our_price, 2, '.', ''); `

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not very strict when it comes to data types. You should be able to subtract two strings (and yes, that is very weird). For example, this works perfectly fine:

```
$var = '100.00';
$var2 = '20.00';
var_dump($var - $var2);
```

That will return `float(80)` as a result.
But if the strings always represent float values, you could [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) them to be sure. Like:

```
$price = (float) $_POST['product_price'];
```

By putting `(float)` in front of the variable, you force `$price` to be a float value. You can do the same for the fee and then you should be able to subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is quite tolerable in that way - it will analyze your variables and coerce their type to float automatically:

```
fike@v-lubuntu:~$ php -r 'var_dump("12.31" - "0.17");'
double(12.14)
```

As said above, you can use `floatval()` or type casting (`$var = (float) $string`) to perform type casting manually. What is 100% must be said is that you should be thousand times aware of what your variables will cast to, since this expression is perfectly valid and will return `true`:

```
true == 'true'
```

To force type checking, you need to use extra equal sign operator:

```
true === 'true' // false
true !== 'true' // true
```